# save data when app closed in flutter provider

Tags: flutter

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

I used this package for the cart and it works.

But when the app closes, the cart model becomes empty.

What can I do for this problem?

I want to save the previous data when the app is opened.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also use the offline database
for example [SQFLITE](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)

Answer (score 0):

Using something like [Shared_Prefs](https://pub.dev/packages?q=shared_preferrences) sould solve it

it will store your data locally and retrieve them in your providers

1. create instance

`SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();`

2. set your data

`await prefs.setInt('counter', 1);`

3. in your provider retrieve if exist like this

```
if(prefs.getInt('counter') != null){
  someVar = prefs.getInt('counter');
}
```

4. you can remove like

`prefs.remove('counter');`

Note: you can save/retrieve with one of the following types

> Only primitive types can be used: int, double, bool, string, and stringList.

Comment: it means i should save my model in separate lists?

Comment: you save data not models, and you can save anything you want as string and convert back in retrieving